# Unity doesn't play animation with C#

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, animator

So, the animation plays on "Play automatically" but when I can't play it from my C#. here's the code running it:

```
[SerializeField]
private GameObject theThing;

theThing.gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>().Play();
//i also tried using Animator but no luck
```

i also have the Legacy turned on in the anim file

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use `Legacy` for the animations, you must set the speed of each `state` in the animation. The following code should do the job:

```
private GameObject theThing;
public void PlayAnim()
{
    foreach (AnimationState state in theThing.GetComponent<Animation>())
    {
        state.speed = 0.5f;
    }
    this.GetComponent<Animation>().Play();
}
```

Comment: I have hardcoded the speed but you could make a variable and change it however you see fit

Comment: I was dumb enough to set the prefab itself to play animation instead of setting its instantiated ones :p

Answer (score 0):

So, my problem was that i set the prefab to play the animation instead of the instantiated one.
I also used Animator again like this:

```
theThingIns.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().Play();
```